# How do I convert LVM partitions to NTFS/Ext?

Tags: lvm, restore, convert

I have an LVM partition that is split into `/projects` (500 GB) and `/backup` (1.5 TB). I cannot mount it because it was on a root machine that crashed. How can I restore the data without do LVM to Ubuntu harddrive?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty well documented in the LVM howtos and elsewhere. Just move the disks to a system with LVM, reassemble the volume group, activate the LVs, and backup like you normally would. I don't see what NTFS has to do with it, unless you're trying to accomplish this from a Windows host. There are drivers out there that can add LVM support to Windows though I've never tried them.